# How to compare two lines of a file and report the mismatched characters?

Tags: python

I have a file containing data as follows:

```
>seq1
TGTACTTTCGGCCCTTAAACTTGTCTGGN
>seq2
NGCACTTTCGGCCCTTATACTTGTCTAGC
```

I want to compare the lines after `>` to report mismatches by position and count of `N` in the data.

```
>seq1
TGTACTTTCGGCCCTTAAACTTGTCTGGN
>seq2
NGCACTTTCGGCCCTTATACTTGTCTAGC
N 1              1        1 N
```

The results are:

```
Count of Mismatches is : 3
Count of N is : 2
Position of Mismatches : 3, 18, 27
Position of N : 1, 29
```

How this can be done in Python?

Comment: `for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(seq1, seq2)): ...`, then just a bunch of `if` statements comparing `a` and `b` and giving you the index in `i`…?

Comment: The steps to solve this problem are:
1. File handling - read the contents of the file and find sequence pairs to compare.
2. Comparison - compare the sequence pairs found in the previous step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First iterate the file as couples of lines and save each sequence to a dict of sequences.

Then, you can [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the two sequences to iterate matching characters and [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) them to get the index:

```py
seqs = {}
with open("test.txt") as f:
    for name, text in zip(f, f):
        seqs[name.strip()] = text.strip()

for name, text in seqs.items():
    print(name, text, sep='\n')

mismatch = []
ns = []
for i, (c1, c2) in enumerate(zip(*seqs.values()), 1):
    if "N" in (c1, c2):
        print("N", end='')
        ns.append(i)
    elif c1 != c2:
        print("1", end='')
        mismatch.append(i)
    else:
        print(end=' ')
print()
print("Count of Mismatches is :", len(mismatch))
print("Count of N is :", len(ns))
print("Position of Mismatches :", *mismatch)
print("Position of N :", *ns)
```

Result:

```
>seq1
TGTACTTTCGGCCCTTAAACTTGTCTGGN
>seq2
NGCACTTTCGGCCCTTATACTTGTCTAGC
N 1              1        1 N
Count of Mismatches is : 3
Count of N is : 2
Position of Mismatches : 3 18 27
Position of N : 1 29
```

Comment: the data is a file not two strings